# Setting Unity AnimatorController default state doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity 2019.4.31f1 (for reasons)

When I try to set the default state of a layer's state machine it has no effect.

I am copying a layer from one animator to another. The source layer has a state machine with a default state ("Idle") and the new one doesn't have anything set (so Unity I assume randomly picks the default state which in my test is "Point L"):

```
Debug.Log("Setting layer " + destinationLayer.stateMachine.defaultState.name + " to " + sourceLayer.stateMachine.defaultState.name);
destinationLayer.stateMachine.defaultState = sourceLayer.stateMachine.defaultState;

Debug.Log("ORIGINAL: " + sourceLayer.stateMachine.defaultState.name);
Debug.Log("RESULT: " + destinationLayer.stateMachine.defaultState.name);
```

```
Setting layer Point L to Idle
Original: Idle
Result: Point L
```

The result should be "Idle" but it doesn't get changed.

Am I not allowed to change a default state once it has been set?

The original layer:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Comment: You might have some variable set that makes transition from Any State to Point L at the very beginning and you feel like it doesn't even run default state.

Comment: You shouldn't really be setting the state like that I believe. The animator subsystem is something to really use through its intended UI. Any time I've tried to do things like this it has bitten me. I think your problem is that the entry state has a transition to point L. I believe no matter what you do, as long as that transition is there, you'll see the behavior you're getting. What's keeping you from simply redirecting that transition to your wanted "default" state?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell the issue, the following piece of code works fine for me:

```
private void ChangeDefaultState(string targetStateName)
{
    var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    var animationController = (animator.runtimeAnimatorController as AnimatorController);
    var baseLayer = animationController.layers[0];

    Debug.Log("The current default state is: " + baseLayer.stateMachine.defaultState.name);

    var targetAnimatorState = System.Array.Find(baseLayer.stateMachine.states, x => x.state != null && x.state.name == targetStateName);

    if (targetAnimatorState.state != null)
    {
        baseLayer.stateMachine.defaultState = targetAnimatorState.state;
        Debug.Log("The default state has been updated to: " + baseLayer.stateMachine.defaultState.name);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Target state not found");
    }
}
```